# pthread gets cancelled before releasing locks

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking, race-condition

I am still very new to multi-threading in C. I have written a simple program that does the following:

The main function starts a number of threads, each waiting for flag `start` to be set using a condition variable. After that the main function starts another thread that sets the flag and notifies all threads via `pthread_cond_broadcast()` that the flag was set.

`start_routine` of the threads that are waiting for the flag to be set (here named worker threads):

```
void* workerThread()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&start_flag_mutex);
  while(!start_flag)
  {
    pthread_cond_wait(&start_flag_condition, &start_flag_mutex);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&start_flag_mutex);

  //Do some work here...
}
```

`start_routine` of the thread that broadcasts the change:

```
void* starterThread()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&start_flag_mutex);
  
  start_flag = true;

  pthread_cond_broadcast(&start_flag_condition);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&start_flag_mutex);
}
```

After the main function starts all the threads, it joins the worker threads and the starter thread in this order. All pthread primitives are initialized before and destroyed after use correctly. In about 1/10 runs my program gets stuck with worker threads waiting on the condition.

My question is: Is it possible that a worker thread that owns the lock for a shared resource (in this case the flag) gets cancelled before releasing it, thus causing the others to wait forever? If so, what can I do to prevent it?

EDIT: For clarity, the worker threads are being cancelled, then joined in the main function once they finished their work.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; ++i)
{
  pthread_cancel(worker_tids[i]);
  pthread_join(worker_tids[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: You might want a [barrier](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_barrier_destroy.3p.html) instead.

Comment: Re, "Is it possible that a worker thread...gets cancelled...?" You mean "cancelled" as in "killed?" "terminated?" Hard to answer that question since you have not showed the whole program. Nothing that you showed would kill a thread, but could something else in your program do it? That depends on what else is in your program.

Comment: P.S., Why does the starter thread need to be a distinct thread? Why can't the main thread start the others? P.P.S., There's a name for what you built. It's called a "turnstile." The threads "go through" it one-by-one just like people going through a turnstile at a sports arena. And, it can be "locked" or "unlocked," just like a turnstile at a sports arena. Question is, why? Why do you want the "worker" threads to all start at almost-but-not-quite the same time? What's the harm in letting some of the threads start a few milliseconds before some of the others?

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. Please provide a demonstration of the problem instead of potentially irrelevant snippets.

Comment: Your thread functions are incorrect.  The entry-point function of a pthreads thread must have *exactly* the signature `void *f(void *)`.  In particular here, they must accept a parameter of type `void *`, even if they ignore it.  I don't think that's actually the cause of your misbehavior, but it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

It sure looks possible to me.  If a worker thread gets the `start_flag_mutex` first, it will prevent the starter thread from proceeding past the lock, so the starter thread will never be able to proceed to the point where it can set `start_flag = true`.

**Edit** Upon re-reading, I'm not sure I understood your question correctly.  I interpreted it as a question about whether you can get deadlock on startup.

Comment: If a worker thread gets the `start_flag_mutex` first, it will test the flag, and finding the flag to be `false`, it will then call `pthread_cond_wait(&start_flag_condition,&start_flag_mutex)`, which will _unlock_ the mutex for the duration of the call.

Comment: I stand corrected, I didn't understand what `pthread_cond_wait` was really doing but closer reading the documentation does say that the mutex is unlocked, then is locked again when the function returns.

Comment: It's also important to note that all these methods have a return values that should be checked to handle exceptional conditions.